Kafka MM2 Replication duplicated
I have two kafka clusters and a kafka connect instance, use mm2 to replicate messages, but I face data duplication.
source Kafka cluster: xx.xx.xx.184:21001,xx.xx.xx.184:21002,xx.xx.xx.184:21003
target Kafka cluster: xx.xx.xx.184:21004,xx.xx.xx.184:21005,xx.xx.xx.184:21006


it's obvious every message was duplicated replication (Value and Timestamp), has anyone encountered and solved this problem?
On the other hand, I created another Kafka connect instance and configured a new MM2 Task, but I couldn't reproduce the data duplication problem. I guess the problem may be the old connect
in stance, I couldn't find any non-normal logs in the connect log file.
a mm2 config as follows :
MirrorSourceConnector
{
  "name": "1-sc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector",
    "replication.factor": "1",
    "offset-syncs.topic.replication.factor": "3",
    "producer.override.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21004,xx.xx.xx.184:21005,xx.xx.xx.184:21006",
    "sync.topic.acls.enabled": "true",
    "consumer.group.id": "test_mm2_04_sc",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "refresh.topics.enabled": "true",
    "topics": "test-04",
    "sync.topic.acls.interval.seconds": "600",
    "source.cluster.alias": "bsdca",
    "refresh.groups.enabled": "true",
    "sync.topic.configs.interval.seconds": "600",
    "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21001,xx.xx.xx.184:21002,xx.xx.xx.184:21003",
    "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "target.cluster.alias": "bsdcb",
    "value.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "offset.lag.max": "100",
    "target.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
    "name": "1-sc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
    "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21004,xx.xx.xx.184:21005,xx.xx.xx.184:21006",
    "sync.topic.configs.enabled": "true",
    "source.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
    "refresh.topics.interval.seconds": "20"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "1-sc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}

MirrorCheckpointConnector
{
  "name": "1-cc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector",
    "replication.factor": "2",
    "sync.group.offsets.interval.seconds": "20",
    "producer.override.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21004,xx.xx.xx.184:21005,xx.xx.xx.184:21006",
    "consumer.group.id": "test_mm2_04_cc",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test-04",
    "emit.checkpoints.interval.seconds": "60",
    "source.cluster.alias": "bsdca",
    "groups": ".*",
    "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21001,xx.xx.xx.184:21002,xx.xx.xx.184:21003",
    "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "target.cluster.alias": "bsdcb",
    "value.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "target.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
    "name": "1-cc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
    "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21004,xx.xx.xx.184:21005,xx.xx.xx.184:21006",
    "checkpoints.topic.replication.factor": "3",
    "refresh.groups.interval.seconds": "600",
    "source.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
    "sync.group.offsets.enabled": "true"
  },
  "tasks": [],
  "type": "source"
}

MirrorHeartbeatConnector
{
  "name": "1-hc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector",
    "replication.factor": "2",
    "producer.override.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21004,xx.xx.xx.184:21005,xx.xx.xx.184:21006",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "heartbeats.topic.replication.factor": "3",
    "source.cluster.alias": "bsdca",
    "source.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21001,xx.xx.xx.184:21002,xx.xx.xx.184:21003",
    "key.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "target.cluster.alias": "bsdcb",
    "value.serializer": "org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter",
    "target.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT",
    "name": "1-hc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
    "target.cluster.bootstrap.servers": "xx.xx.xx.184:21004,xx.xx.xx.184:21005,xx.xx.xx.184:21006",
    "emit.heartbeats.interval.seconds": "1",
    "source.cluster.security.protocol": "PLAINTEXT"
  },
  "tasks": [
    {
      "connector": "1-hc-88884abe403a44b0887107e636c43f4a",
      "task": 0
    }
  ],
  "type": "source"
}


solved, I finally found another Kafka-connect instance with the same offset-topic state configuration
